# How to set character encoding for OpenBSD tty session?

Tags: locale, openbsd, character-encoding

On OpenBSD, in order to appropriately see language specific characters in X sessions all I need to do is set `LC_CTYPE` to one of the values listed using `locale -a`. I do this by adding `export LC_CTYPE=xx_YY.UTF-8` to the .Xsession file.

Is there any way to get similar result for tty sessions?

Comment: you could also configure your shell (e.g. ksh) to set suitable locale environment variables

Comment: any details or suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

SSH, `wscons(4)`, or other means of terminal access do not fall under
the X11 configuration. One means to configure the resulting shell of
such access methods is to set suitable environment variables in the
shell configuration. Assuming `ksh(1)`, a typical way to do this
would be to set

```
export ENV=/home/user/.kshrc
```

in `~/.profile` and then in the `~/.kshrc` file set the necessary
`export LC_CTYPE=...` value. Other shells (e.g. `fish` or `zsh`) will
vary in how and in what file environment variables are set, check their
manual for details.

Another method would be to create a new (or configure an existing) login
class to set suitable environment variables for the user(s) in question;
see `setenv` under `login.conf(5)`. `doas.conf(5)` may also need (a
different) `setenv` if the locale settings need to work as another user.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, it does't work. I have added the mention export command to `.kshrc` file and what you suggested to `.profile`. It certainly modifies how characters are displayed but the result is different than expected. For example it changes the "-" (hyphen) in man pages, which is weird btw, but all language specific symbols are still incorrectly.